# How to send cookie with Erlang httpc

Tags: http, cookies, erlang

How to send cookie content with erlang http client *httpc*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe like this:

```
Url = "http://example.org",
httpc:request(get,  {Url, [{"Cookie", "name1=value1;name2=value2"}]}.
```